# How to update single value inside specific json array item using redux (Flatlist item click)?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a Flatlist with displaying name and status,
I want to toggle status of the user by clicking the  flatlist item click.
I have created the redux action and redux reducer for this purpose .But unable to change the curresponding status.

```
itemClick (item,index) {
  const value=false;
  this.props.listItemClick({props:'status',value});
  }


 export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
        case LIST_CLICK:
        console.log(action.payload.props);
            return {...state,[action.payload.props]: action.payload.value};
        default:
            return state;

    }
};
```

but not able change status corresponding to specified user. for example Raj status to false

```
{
"response": [{
  "name": "RAJ",
   "status": true

 }, {
 "name": "RAM",
  "status": true,

}]
}


  <FlatList
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
     removeClippedSubviews={false}
     data={this.props.response}
     ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.flatListItemSeparator}
     ListFooterComponent={this.flatListItemSeparator}
     keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
     renderItem={({item,index}) => this.renderFlatListItem(item,index)}/>
```

Comment: you can merge data before returning

Comment: i am new in redux.Let me know how to do this

Comment: you can modify your object befor console.log(action.payload.props);

Comment: but same json result not able to change status to false

Comment: use Object.assign([],yourData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are trying to achieve, but i'll give it a try.

```
//call Action 
this.props.listItemClick('RAJ',false});

//Action
export const listItemClick = (user,status) => {
    return {
        type: LIST_CLICK,
        payload: { user, status }
    };
}; 

 export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
        case LIST_CLICK:
            //replace YOUR_DATA with your state var 
            return {...state, YOUR_DATA: [state.YOUR_DATA.map((val,index) => {
                   if (val.name === action.payload.user) {
                      return { ...val, status: action.payload.status };
                   }
                   return { ...val };
            })]};
        default:
            return state;

    }
};
```

Comment: i changed return {...val};  and its working fine.only issue i am facing after changing value now i am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined.

Comment: @praj that's another issue and has nothing to do with my implementation ;) probably you need to ask this in another question. edit: your flatlist code seems fine

Comment: i found the issue:before calling redux    Array [
  Object {
  "name": "RAJ",
    "status": true,
     
   
  },
  Object {
    "name": "RAM",
   "status": true,
  }
  
] after Array [

   Array [
  Object {
  "name": "RAJ",
    "status": true,
     
   
  },
  Object {
    "name": "RAM",
   "status": true,
  }
  
]
] ..top array is extra

Comment: i think you have to remove my comment '//replace YOUR_DATA with your state var'

Comment: return {...state, response: [state.response.map((val,index) => {