# React redux updates flatlist item but turns item into an Array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I am using react redux with react native, I have a flatlist of photos. When I click the like button, I'd like to update only a single photo in the flatlist. The following code seems to work, and the photo's like status is updated, but somehow my feed is messed up after the update. Before the update, `this.props.feed[index]` is a single object, after the update, `this.props.feed[index]` becomes an array of objects, what am I doing wrong? I got the idea from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47651395/10906478

But it also seems really inefficient to loop through all items of flatlist to find one that matches the passed in photoId. Is there a better way?

Screen:

```
toggleLike = async(photoId, index) => {
    console.log("before: ", this.props.feed[index]);
    await this.props.toggleLike(photoId);
    console.log("after: ", this.props.feed[index]);
}

...

<FlatList
    data = {this.props.feed}
    keyExtractor = {(_, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem = {({item, index}) => (
        <View key={index}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.toggleLike(item.photoId, index)}>
                <Text>Button</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )}
/>
```

Action

```
export const toggleLike = (photoId) => async(dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: "UPDATE_ITEM", photoId: photoId})
}
```

Reducer

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "UPDATE_ITEM":
            return {...state, feed: [state.feed.map((item,_) => {
                if (item.photoId === action.photoId) {
                   return { ...item, liked: !item.liked };
                }
                return { ...item };
            })]};

        // other cases
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `map` inside an array, which returns a nested array:

```js
return {...state, feed: /* Here ->*/[state.feed.map((item,_) => {
    if (item.photoId === action.photoId) {
        return { ...item, liked: !item.liked };
    }
    return { ...item };
})]};
```

This should do:

```js
return {
  ...state, // Current state
  feed: state.feed.map((item, _) => { // map returns a new array
    if (item.photoId === action.photoId) {
      item.liked = !item.liked;
    }
    return item;
  })
}
```

Comment: Getting a property assignment expected error on `=> {`

Comment: Whoops, added parens.  Gist of the idea is there, though.

Comment: Thanks! Is this actually the most efficient way to accomplish this? Because looping through all items of the list to find an ID that match seems an overkill?

Comment: There might be more efficient ways, but I wouldn't worry too much about it unless you have an absurdly long array.

Answer (score 0):

For the feed being an array, look closely at your code. You'll see you have wrapped the value of feed in square brackets and run a map on the array. So feed is an array, and the map is also an array. This is why you have an array of objects at each index point for state.feed. I'd normally suggest you get rid of the surrounding square brackets and let your map create the array.

However, that isn't actually the root cause of the issue, and there is a more thorough solution.

If the need is to find the matching ID and update the "liked" value without disturbing the order of the array, try using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead of map on the array. Find the index where your item is and update just that value. You might need to make a clone of the array and inner objects if it complains about directly mutating a Redux store value.

Best of luck!

Comment: Wouldn't findIndex have to loop through the list anyway? So performance wise it's the same as creating a map? Not sure if I'm understanding your answer fully. Can you put it into code